# Equivalent for $v_{n+1}=v_n\ln(v_n)$

Tags: sequences-and-series, asymptotics

Do you know how to get an equivalent for $(v_n)$ defined by $v_0>\mathrm{e}$ and $\forall n\in\mathbb{N},\; v_{n+1}=v_n\ln(v_n)$ ? Thank you.

Comment: do you mean turn the recurrence relation into an explicit function

Comment: @HenryLee IMO  at least we can say, algebraic finite closed form doesn't exist.

Comment: @lonestudent yep the only thing I've thought of is $v_n=\ln W(v_{n+1})$ but I don't think that will lead anywhere

Comment: @HenryLee I thought maybe if I got rid of $\ln$  I would get an "ease" (not much has changed actually).  I wrote $v_n=e^{u_n}, v_{n+1}=u_ne^{u_n}$ as the new sequence. But, I knew it wouldn't work..

Comment: Thank you. I meant $v_n\sim ?$ when $n\longrightarrow +\infty$.